# Monitoring application code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, performance-testing, webclient

Ι am using visual studio 2015 rc community.

Ι write simple function that should download html source pages, and show the result richtextbox.

For Example:

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RichTextBox1.Text = PagesDownloader(4, 8) ' Download Pages from 4 to 8
    End Sub

    Private Function PagesDownloader(StartPage As Integer, EndPage As Integer)
        Const SiteUrl As String = "http://MySite.co.il/TestPage.php?id={0}" ' Every Html Page size is 30MB
        Dim WebClnt As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim SourceResults As New StringBuilder

        For i = StartPage To EndPage - 1
            SourceResults.AppendLine("Page: " & i)
            SourceResults.AppendLine(String.Format(WebClnt.DownloadString(SiteUrl), i))
            SourceResults.AppendLine("-------------" & vbNewLine)
        Next

        Return SourceResults.ToString

    End Function


End Class
```

the steps of the code after he is run, is something like that:

1. Get connected with the server
2. Download the page from the server
3. write the html page to memory
4. build string with html source code
5. repeat the steps until the "end page" come to last number (finish).

Now I ask, how I can get the time for every code line that take to program / my PC for executing the code? And how much power is taken from hardware in my PC (and from what is take)?

For example, if the html source code file size is 30 MB, is depending on my internet speed and the server speed. How do I get that information?

**I hope this is understandable, if not I'd be happy to try to explain again.
Overall, I am looking monitor the performance of the code, and how it affects hardware.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StopWatch class to measure how long your code is executing.

```
Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
stopWatch.Start()
Thread.Sleep(10000) ' to simulate a time consuming task
stopWatch.Stop()
Dim ts As TimeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
As for the second part of the question:
Is there a way to watch on hardware that it affects, and how much power it takes (CPU, memory, hard disk, Internet, GPU)?